# Can I replace a non-polarized electrolytic capacitor with a ceramic disc capacitor?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor, ceramic

I need to replace a non-polarized electrolytic with a ceramic disc capacitor, can I do that? If not, is there other ways to replace it?

Comment: Maybe, if the ratings are appropriate - what is the exact application?

Answer (score 4):

Non-polarized capacitors are supersets of polarized capacitors.  Polarization is not a issue when replacing a electrolytic with a ceramic.

In general, you can replace a polarized capacitor with a polarized or non-polarized capacitor with the same capacitance, and with a voltage rating of the original or higher.  Non-polarized capacitors may only be replaced with other non-polarized capacitors, unless you know the circuit will only ever apply voltage in one polarity.

In a few unusual cases, the circuit be relying on the electrolytic having some minimum ESR.  A ceramic won't work then because those have very low ESR.  This is unlikely, but not totally unheard of.  There have been power supplies that relied on a minimum out cap ESR for stability.  You are less likely to run into that in newer designs, now that ceramics are readily available with 10s of µF capacitance.